# How to convert mysql array result into new array for json encoding

Tags: php

I can’t seem to get the result I need.  Here is the array as it is provided by the sql query:

```
Array (
 [0] => Array ( 
     [id] => 7
     [description] => Accepted )
 [1] => Array ( 
     [id] => 8
     [description] => Declined )
 [2] => Array (
     [id] => 11 
     [description] => Deferred ) 
     )
```

Here is the format for how I need to have it foreach of the objects listed above:

```
['7'][‘7’] = “Accepted”;
['7'][‘8’] = “Declined ”;
['7'][‘11’] = “Deferred”;
```

...where the first array[‘7’] is an added value and needed for each object.

Seems easy enough, but the foreach statements I created return an error “cannot use scalar value as an array”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$rows = /*Your Data above*/
$data = array('7'=>array());
foreach($rows as $row)
    $data['7'][$row['id']] = $row['description'];

$jsonData = json_encode($data);
```

Might get 'er done

Comment: Close, but not quite: {"7":{"7":"Accepted","8":"Declined","11":"Deferred"}}

Comment: That looks correct to me. You wont get it showing up as {{"7":{"7":"Accepted"}}, {"7":{"8":"Declined"}}, {"7":{"11":"Deferred, but accepted"}}} because the index 7 is common among the elements. the '7' index will only showup once when json_encoded

Comment: Gotcha.  You're right.  I was just contemplating that very thing.  Thanks, man... :)

Comment: Sorry for the follow up, I'll open a new question if needed; but now when I array_merge($rowsA, $rowsB, and $rowsC) (not provided in the above example) with the same format you provided, I lose the leading array (in my case '7', '6', and '5'). Does array_merge not take that into account?

Comment: array_merge() flattens an array. duh. Sorry.